# Print nested list as a matrix

Tags: python, nested-lists

i have a list which i need to print as a matrix!
nestedList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

```
   **i want the output to be**
     [1,2,3]
     [4,5,6]
     [7,8,9]
```

Comment: Try `print(*nestedList, sep="\n")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will do a thing (although there is clearly no explanation why you need this)

```
"[" + "\n".join(str(i) for i in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) + "]"
```